# Correct approach for duplicating html elements for zoom to full-screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that looks like this...

```
<body>

<div id="detailDiv1" style="height 100px; overflow:auto">
</div>

<div id="detailDiv2" style="height 100px; overflow:auto">
</div>

<div id="detailDiv3" style="height 100px; overflow:auto">
</div>

<div id="detailDiv4" style="height 100px; overflow:auto">
</div>

</body>
```

Each of the detailDivs are loaded dynamically with rows of content (often lots of rows, causing a vertical scroll bar to appear inside the detailDivs).  Each row inside each detailDiv contains a small image, some text, and a couple of buttons that increment counts in the DB that are then dynamically updated (ajax) on the row itself.

Since each of these detailDivs is so small, I'm trying to implement a "view as full screen" option but am struggling to come up with an elegant plan...

I know that I'm going to use a bootstrap modal to present the full-screen version of each detailDiv, and I'm guessing I need to duplicate the html from each detailDiv - something like...

```
$('#myFullScreenModal').html($('#detailDiv1').html());
```

That will load the content correctly, but of course the elements will have the exact same names (and therefore the interaction with the DB will be interfered with unless I empty the original container first, and reload it when the modal is closed).

But those options sound pretty hacky to me, and so I'm wondering whether there's a more standard way of achieving this effect without having to duplicate large chunks of html.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `position: fixed` on the `div` in question then expand it out. That way you don't have to copy anything at all, you're just displaying that exact element as "fullscreen".

```js
$('.go-fullscreen').click(function() {
 var $parent = $(this).parent();
  if ($parent.hasClass('fullscreen')) {
   $parent.removeClass('fullscreen');
  } else {
   $parent.addClass('fullscreen');
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.red { background-color: #F00; }
.green { background-color: #0F0; }
.blue { background-color: #00F; }
div.fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
  <button class="go-fullscreen">Fullscreen</button>
</div>
<div class="blue">
  <p>10</p>
  <p>20</p>
  <p>30</p>
  <p>40</p>
  <p>50</p>
  <p>60</p>
  <p>70</p>
  <p>80</p>
  <button class="go-fullscreen">Fullscreen</button>
</div>
<div class="green">
  <p>100</p>
  <p>200</p>
  <p>300</p>
  <p>400</p>
  <p>500</p>
  <p>600</p>
  <p>700</p>
  <p>800</p>
  <button class="go-fullscreen">Fullscreen</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot - knew it was worth asking that question!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this which will make it enlarge to a size you can configure :) 
There is a css part and a jquery part. You could do this for them all. Of course change the scale to the desired size. Maybe not a full page takeover though will do a similar job. Hope you find it useful.

CSS

```
.transition {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); 
 -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
 -o-transform: scale(1.5);
 transform: scale(1.5);  
}
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('.detailDiv1')
.on('mouseover', function() {
         $('.detailDiv1').addClass('transition')
    })
.on('mouseout', function() {
         $('.detailDiv1').removeClass('transition');

    });
});
```